# Get status of a submitted Gnosis Safe transaction by safeTxHash

Tags: gnosis-safe

Is there a way to get the status of a gnosis-safe transaction that was just signed and submitted to the blockchain? Basically, is there an API to check whether the submitted transaction is in mempool assuming all I have is the safeTxHash?

Answer (score 2):

If you have the `safeTxHash`, you can look it up through the `/v1/multisig-transactions/{safe_tx_hash}` endpoint of the the [TransactionService API](https://safe-transaction-mainnet.safe.global/) (link for the Ethereum Safe API, as an example).  The response will return the executed `transactionHash`.

Edit: Upon more discussion with Safe, it seems the transactionHash is not populated until the event is broadcast, when the transaction is fully executed. Therefore, the only way to get this information would be to engage in a third-party service that watches wallets for all of your signers.

Comment: thanks for quick response.  Unless I'm doing something wrong, `/v1/multisig-transactions/{safe_tx_hash}` doesn't seem to immediately return the transactionHash unless the block/txn is minted. This is on polygon or eth mainnet.

Answer (score 0):

Yes. You can use the [safe-apps-sdk](https://github.com/safe-global/safe-apps-sdk/tree/master/packages/safe-apps-sdk) to [retrieve transaction status with `getBySafeTxHash`](https://github.com/safe-global/safe-apps-sdk/tree/master/packages/safe-apps-sdk#retrieving-transactions-status).

```
    import SafeAppsSDK from '@gnosis.pm/safe-apps-sdk';

    ...
    
    const sdk = new SafeAppsSDK({
      allowedDomains: [/app.safe.global/],
      debug: false,
    });

    const signed = await sdk.txs.signMessage("Message to sign");

    const tx = await sdk.txs.getBySafeTxHash(signed?.safeTxHash);
```

Comment: This doesn't work for transactions that are submitted to blockchain but not yet mined

Comment: Did you try it? I think it gives you the txHash, which you can then use to look it up. https://github.com/safe-global/safe-apps-sdk/blob/5bc7d9d55d6dfc02d705fd5b63f8dd64827c87fd/packages/safe-apps-sdk/README.md#retrieving-transactions-status

Comment: Not sure we’re talking about the same thing. The API you shared works if the transaction has been mined. I want to know if the transaction has been submitted + is in the mempool but hasn’t confirmed yet. The API you’re referring to does not look at the mempool when I tried it.

Comment: I need this to show progress bar on the app side while the transaction is getting confirmed on the Blockchain. How this helps

Comment: Where do you see that it only works when it has been mined?
The moment you sign, you'll get a `safeTxHash`.
The documentation says:   

"Once you received safe transaction hash, you might want to get the status of the transaction (was it executed? how many confirmations does it have?):"

Comment: So you have the`safeTxHash`.   
  
1. You call `getBySafeTxHash` with the safeTxHash, it will return a [TransactionDetail](https://github.com/safe-global/safe-gateway-typescript-sdk/blob/11a1dff6319533f2266c9cbba2e8e98c36e25782/src/types/transactions.ts#L378-L388) object. There you have the `txHash`.  
2. Use ethers/web3.js to fetch information about the transaction.